# Python requests returns: CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to login to my account as follow:

```
>> session=requests.Session()
>> session.get('http://mywebsite.com')
>> csrftoken=session.cookies['ThisIsMyToken']
```

But the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 276, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 331, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='ThisIsMyToken', domain=None, path=None"
```

Comment: Looks like there's no cookie named `ThisIsMyToken`. Is the server sending it?

Comment: Yes it is ..I am sure cookie is correct...

Comment: What is the output from printing session.cookies?

Comment: This is something completely different from `ThisIsMyToken`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the cookie from the request, you should access it from the response, something like this:

```
resp = session.get('http://mywebsite.com')
csrftoken = resp.cookies['ThisIsMyToken']
```

Comment: Do a `print resp.txt`, what do you get?

Comment: It returns me source url of site with different csrftoken

Comment: Are the cookies listed there? if yes, can you post the contents?

Comment: ofcourse: `<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='csrftoken', value='w0brNBgly7GX6jAsTGm27w2oRd5nJKSd', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='django-blog-zinnia.com', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1461770829, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>`

Comment: Well, it looks like the name of the cookie is `csrftoken`, not `ThisIsMyToken`

Comment: shouldn't be `w0brNBgly7GX6jAsTGm27w2oRd5nJKSd`? I mean the value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76507/discussion-between-cristik-and-mortezalsc).